# How to export an ad-hoc SQLServer query blob data to a binary file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I simply want to be able to export jpg data from a single record to a file without having to write a program every time.

Query:

```
select Media from tbl_GEO_ElementImage where ElementImageID = 64902
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a command line utility to allow simple unattended export of multiple image records.

```
Usage:
RunSQLOLEDB "[connection string]" "[query]"

e.g.
To extact all images from table Image into separate files 1.jpg, 2.jpg, etc.
SQLImageOut "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=(local);..." "SELECT CONVERT(varchar(50), ImageID)+'.jpg', ImageData from Image"
or        
SQLImageOut @ConnectionString.txt @Query.sql
```

[Download Binary](https://github.com/tekkies/SQLImageOut/blob/master/bin/Release/SQLImageOut.exe?raw=true)

[GitHub Source](https://github.com/tekkies/SQLImageOut)

Answer (score 4):

Use the command line BCP utility:

```
c:\temp\>bcp "select Media from tbl_GEO_ElementImage where ElementImageID = 64902" queryout "001.jpg" -T
```

When promped, give the following answers:

```
    Enter the file storage type of field Media [image]: <Enter>
    Enter prefix-length of field Media [4]: 0
    Enter length of field Media [0]: <Enter>
    Enter field terminator [none]: <Enter>

Do you want to save this format information in a file? [Y/n] n
```

Comment: I had to do this for multiple records, so I ended up writing a script to generate a series of these statements, adding the additional "-n" flag to avoid prompting for values. Unfortunately it did add the 4 byte prefix since it's the default, but another quick script removed the first 4 bytes afterwards. Thanks for the post, this really helped me out!